# django temporarily disable signals

Tags: django, model, signals

I have a signal callback in django:

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=MediumCategory)
def update_category_descendants(sender, **kwargs):
    
    def children_for(category):
        return MediumCategory.objects.filter(parent=category)
    
    def do_update_descendants(category):
        children = children_for(category)
        descendants = list() + list(children)
        
        for descendants_part in [do_update_descendants(child) for child in children]:
            descendants += descendants_part
        
        category.descendants.clear()
        for descendant in descendants:
            if category and not (descendant in category.descendants.all()):
                category.descendants.add(descendant)
                category.save()
        return list(descendants)
    
    # call it for update
    do_update_descendants(None)
```

...but in the signal handler's body I'm using `.save()` on the same model `MediumCategory`.  This causes the signal to be dispatched again. How can I disable it?

The perfect solution would be a `with` statement with some 'magic' inside.

**UPDATE:**
Here is my final solution, if anyone interested:

```py
class MediumCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    parameters = models.ManyToManyField(AdvertisementDescriptonParameter, blank=True)
    count_mediums = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    count_ads = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    
    descendants = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, null=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(MediumCategory, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
(...)
@receiver(post_save, sender=MediumCategory)
def update_category_descendants(sender=None, **kwargs):
    def children_for(category):
        return MediumCategory.objects.filter(parent=category)
    
    def do_update_descendants(category):
        children = children_for(category)
        descendants = list() + list(children)
        
        for descendants_part in [do_update_descendants(child) for child in children]:
            descendants += descendants_part
        
        if category:
            category.descendants.clear()
            for descendant in descendants:
                category.descendants.add(descendant)
        return list(descendants)
    
    # call it for update
    do_update_descendants(None)
```

Comment: I found an answer and I wrote [it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532539/want-to-disable-signals-in-django-testing/70848580#70848580). Hope can help someone :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perhaps I'm wrong, but I think that `category.save()` is not needed in your code, add() is enough because change is made in descendant but in category.

Also, to avoid signals you can:

- [Disconnect signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#disconnecting-signals) and reconnect.
- Use [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update): `Descendant.objects.filter( pk = descendant.pk ).update( category = category )`

Comment: ok, that's what I was looking for: `disconnect` is the solution, putting it into `with` statement is a matter of purity :) But after removing `save()`, `disconnect` is not needed. Perfect.

Comment: and make disconnect + reconnect atomically consistent, no matter what exception appears after disconnection. Also, do you care about other threads?

Comment: Here's the guide: https://blog.theletstream.com/moneky-patching-save-and-bypassing-signals-in-django-4a28e38b3b7b

Answer (score 21):

To disable a signal on your model, a simple way to go is to set an attribute on the current instance to prevent upcoming signals firing.

This can be done using a simple decorator that checks if the given instance has the **'skip_signal'** attribute, and if so prevents the method from being called:

```
from functools import wraps

def skip_signal():
    def _skip_signal(signal_func):
        @wraps(signal_func)
        def _decorator(sender, instance, **kwargs):
            if hasattr(instance, 'skip_signal'):
                return None
            return signal_func(sender, instance, **kwargs)  
        return _decorator
    return _skip_signal
```

You can now use it this way:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
@skip_signal()
def my_model_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.some_field = my_value
    # Here we flag the instance with 'skip_signal'
    # and my_model_post_save won't be called again
    # thanks to our decorator, avoiding any signal recursion
    instance.skip_signal  = True
    instance.save()
```

Hope This helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Why is it not DRY and consistent?

Comment: @coler-j ig there was some exception after signal disconnection and before reconnection, then signal will be left disconnected which can be fatal for your application.

Comment: Doesnt Dry mean Don't Repeat Yourself?

Comment: If disconnecting a signal was not DRY, I don't think Django would offer a way to disconnect them. In my use case, I am performing some updates inside a signal that end up re-triggering the signal. I want to prevent that from being recursive.

Comment: @Bobort you are right, my comment was lacking specificity, I edited my answer to remove the « DRY » comment.

Comment: If you are connecting signals using `connect` the `skip_decorator` overrides the firing of signal and hence signals are not fired.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution to **temporary disable signal receiver
per instance** which allows to use it on **production** (bc it is thread-safe)

**[usage.py]**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

payment = Payment()
with mute_signals_for(payment, signals=[post_save]):
   payment.save()  # handle_payment signal receiver will be skipped
```

**[code.py]**

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from functools import wraps

MUTE_SIGNALS_ATTR = '_mute_signals'


def mutable_signal_receiver(func):
    """Decorator for signals to allow to skip them by setting attr MUTE_SIGNALS_ATTR on instance,
    which can be done via mute_signals_for"""
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(sender, instance, signal, **kwargs):
        mute_signals = getattr(instance, MUTE_SIGNALS_ATTR, False)
        if mute_signals is True:
            pass  # skip all signals
        elif isinstance(mute_signals, list) and signal in mute_signals:
            pass  # skip user requested signal
        else:  # allow signal receiver
            return func(sender=sender, instance=instance, signal=signal, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@contextmanager
def mute_signals_for(instance, signals):
    """Context manager to skip signals for @instance (django model), @signals can be
    True to skip all signals or list of specified signals, like [post_delete, post_save] """
    try:
        yield setattr(instance, MUTE_SIGNALS_ATTR, signals)
    finally:
        setattr(instance, MUTE_SIGNALS_ATTR, False)
```

**[signals.py]**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Payment, dispatch_uid='post_payment_signal')
@mutable_signal_receiver
def handle_payment(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """called after payment is registered in the system."""
```

Comment: Hi @pymen. Thank you for this idea of muting signals. I've been trying to make your code working and to me it seems like there's an issue in `mutable_signal_receiver` method, namely at condition `elif isinstance(mute_signals, list) and signal in mute_signals:` where is signal compared with items of passed list. It's comparison between python function reference and django.db.models.signals.ModelSignal and condition is never met. So for now I'm simply compairing  `__name__` variables of both `func` parameter and items of `mute_signals`. Don't you have this issue?

Comment: @MichalPůlpán you are right, i have fixed the usage example to pass `post_save` to signals which should be muted. Same approach could be applied to signal handlers, just need to use different attribute like MUTE_HANDLERS_ATTR

Answer (score 1):

Where the previous answers demonstrate how to do this without external libraries, django-model-utils offers a clean way to do exactly this. The advantage of the library is that the code is explicit. Performing a bulk_create or filter followed by an update doesn't make it clear that you want to disable the signal. Another advantage is that the save() method may perform additional validation.

```py
from model_utils.models import SaveSignalHandlingModel

class Film(SaveSignalHandlingModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

film = Film(title="Cidade de Deus")
film.save(signals_to_disable=["post_save"])
```

See the post here: https://django.wtf/blog/disable-django-model-signals/