# Want to disable signals in Django testing

Tags: django, django-testing, django-signals

So I have various signals and handlers which are sent across apps. However, when I perform tests / go into 'testing mode', I want these handlers to be disabled.

Is there a Django-specific way of disabling signals/handlers when in testing mode? I can think of a very simple way (of including the handlers within an if TESTING clause) but I was wondering if there was a better way built into Django?...

Comment: Perhaps you can declare a flag variable in your settings_test.py and only bind signals when this flag is to false. Like 'DEBUG' flag. An easy way is to create your own signal functions. I will be posted for most elegant approach.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there is not. You can easily make a conditional connection though:

```
import sys

if not 'test' in sys.argv:
    signal.connect(listener, sender=FooModel)
```

Comment: I was going to :)....Tried to accept it initially but had to wait before I could accept....so went and did something else first

Comment: Notice that tests always run with `DEBUG = False` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#other-test-conditions)), so in this case the signals will still be connected in testing.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer because of the comment from @julen

Comment: @EmilStenström You are right. I just updated the answer.

Answer (score 127):

I found this question when looking to disable a signal for a set of test cases and Germano's answer lead me to the solution but it takes the opposite approach so I thought I'd add it.

In your test class:

```
class MyTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # do some setup
        signals.disconnect(listener, sender=FooModel)
```

Instead of adding decision code to adding the signal I instead disabled it at the point of testing which feels like a nicer solution to me (as the tests should be written around the code rather than the code around the tests). Hopefully is useful to someone in the same boat!

Edit: Since writing this I've been introduced to another way of disabling signals for testing. This requires the [factory_boy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/factory_boy) package (v2.4.0+) which is very useful for simplifying tests in Django. You're spoilt for choice really:

```
import factory
from django.db.models import signals

class MyTest(TestCase):
    @factory.django.mute_signals(signals.pre_save, signals.post_save)
    def test_something(self):
```

Caveat thanks to ups: it mutes signals inside factory and when an object is created, but not further inside test when you want to make explicit save() - signal will be unmuted there. If this is an issue then using the simple disconnect in setUp is probably the way to go.

Comment: Great! This should be the accepted answer, as the other requires rewriting source code (potentially code that isn't your own).

Comment: @krischan: comment to factory - it mutes signals inside `factory` and when an object is created, but not further inside test when you want to make explicit `save()` - signal will be unmuted there.

Comment: @ups ah interesting I didn't know that! I'll edit the answer to include that note

Comment: @krischan I caution against the edited solution and prefer the first. Especially for disabling `pre_save` and `post_save`. Who knows what other critical things are listening on those. I think its better to **mute/mock the receiver (explicit) than the sender (could be connected to many receivers implicitly being muted)**

Comment: That `signal.disconnect` should be `signals.disconnect`

Comment: @KenColton how do you go about mocking the receiver? I tried patching it where the receiver is defined (since I don't import it in the view) but it didn't seem to patch the receiver.

Answer (score 34):

Here's a full example with imports on how to disable a specific signal in a test, if you don't want to use FactoryBoy.

```
from django.db.models import signals
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyTest(TestCase):

    def test_no_signal(self):
        signals.post_save.disconnect(sender=MyModel, dispatch_uid="my_id")

        ... after this point, the signal is disabled ...
```

This should be matched against your receiver, this example would match this receiver:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel, dispatch_uid="my_id")
```

I tried to disable the signal without specifying the *dispatch_uid* and it didn't work.

Comment: Great answer, as it includes the import statements and the right way to invoke disconnect on `ModelSignal` (e.g: `post_save`). Here: +1

Answer (score 11):

All the answers didn't work for me except when I used [Factory Boy](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/blob/master/factory/django.py) by @krischan.

In my case, I want to disable signals that are part of another package [django_elasticsearch_dsl](https://github.com/django-es/django-elasticsearch-dsl) which I couldn't locate the `reciever` or the `dispatch_uid`.

I don't want to add Factory Boy package, and I managed to disable the signals by reading its code to know how the signals are muted and it turned out very simple:

```py
from django.db.models import signals

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_no_signal(self):
        signals.post_save.receivers = []
```

We can replace `post_save` with appropriate signal we want to disable, also we can put this in a `setUp` method for all tests.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following

```py
from factory.django import mute_signals
from django.db.models import signals
def test_your_code():
    with mute_signals(signals.post_save):
        # ... code that doesn't trigger signals
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and wasn't able to successfully disconnect my signal using `signals.post_save.disconnect()`. Found [this](https://devblog.kogan.com/blog/disable-signal-receivers-in-your-django-tests) alternative approach that creates a decorator to override the `SUSPEND_SIGNALS` setting on specified tests and signals. Might be useful for anyone in the same boat.

First, create the decorator:

```
import functools

from django.conf import settings
from django.dispatch import receiver

def suspendingreceiver(signal, **decorator_kwargs):
    def our_wrapper(func):
        @receiver(signal, **decorator_kwargs)
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def fake_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
            if settings.SUSPEND_SIGNALS:
                return
            return func(sender, **kwargs)
        return fake_receiver
    return our_wrapper
```

Replace the usual `@receiver` decorator on your signal with the new one:

```
@suspendingreceiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def mymodel_post_save(sender, **kwargs):
    work()
```

Use Django's [`override_settings()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#override_settings) on your TestCase:

```
@override_settings(SUSPEND_SIGNALS=True)
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_method(self):
        Model.objects.create()  # post_save_receiver won't execute
```

Thanks to Josh Smeaton, who wrote the blog.

Answer (score 4):

If you connect receivers to signals in `AppConfig.ready`, which is recommended by documentation, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions, you can create an alternative `AppConfig` for your tests with other signal receivers.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is using a fixture. just place this function inside your test file outside any class this will run automatically.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True) # Automatically use in tests.
def mute_signals(request):
    post_save.receivers = []
    pre_save.receivers = []
```

for more details see this https://www.cameronmaske.com/muting-django-signals-with-a-pytest-fixture/

Answer (score 0):

[Factory library](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) has a function that you can use as fixture on functions.
Here is an example on how to implement it.

```
from django.db.models import signals
from factory.django import mute_signals

from app.models import Model

@mute_signals(signals.pre_save, signals.post_save)
def function():
    instance = Model.objects.get(id=1)
    instance.attribute = "modify"
    instance.save()
```