# How to test signals when using factory_boy with muted signals

Tags: django, factory-boy

I am using factory_boy package and `DjangoModelFactory` to generate a factory model with muted signals

```
@factory.django.mute_signals(signals.post_save)
class SomeModelTargetFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    name = factory.Sequence(lambda x: "Name #{}".format(x))
    ...
```

I have a `post_save` signal connected to the model:

```
def send_notification(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        send_email(...)
post_save.connect(send_notification, SomeModel)
```

How can I test the signals works when I create an instance of the model using the factory class?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some solutions for the direct question. Followed by a caution.

#### A) Instead of turning off the signals, [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) the side effects

```
@mock.patch('send_email')
def test_mocking_signal_side_effects(self, mocked_send_email):
    my_obj = SomeModelTargetFactory()

    # mocked version of send_email was called
    self.assertEqual(mocked_send_email.call_count, 1)

    my_obj.foo = 'bar'
    my_obj.save()

    # didn't call send_email again
    self.assertEqual(mocked_send_email.call_count, 1)
```

*Note: mock was separate package before joining standard lib in 3.3*

#### B) [Use as context manager](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/orms.html#factory.django.mute_signals) so you can selectively disable in your tests

This would leave the signals on by default, but you can selectively disable:

```
def test_without_signals(self):
    with factory.django.mute_signals(signals.post_save):
        my_obj = SomeModelTargetFactory()

        # ... perform actions w/o signals and assert  ...
```

#### C) Mute signals and an extended version of the base factory

```
class SomeModelTargetFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    name = factory.Sequence(lambda x: "Name #{}".format(x))
    # ...


@factory.django.mute_signals(signals.post_save)
class SomeModelTargetFactoryNoSignals(SomeModelTargetFactory):
    pass
```

I've never tried this, but it seems like it should work. Additionally, if you just need the objects for a quick unit test where persistence isn't required, maybe [FactoryBoy's BUILD strategy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#strategies) is a viable option.

#### Caution: Muting signals, especially like post_save can hide nasty bugs

There are easily findable references about how using signals in your own code can create a false sense of decoupling (`post_save` for example, *essentially is the same* as overriding and extending the `save` method. I'll let you research that to see if it applies to your use case.

Would definitely think twice about making it the default.

A safer approach is to **"mute"/mock the receiver/side effect, not the sender**.

The default Django model signals are used frequently by third party packages. Muting those can hide hard to track down bugs due to intra-package interaction.

Defining and calling (and then muting if needed) *your own* signals is better, but often is just re-inventing a method call. [Sentry is a good example of signals being used well in a large codebase.](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/blob/master/src/sentry/signals.py)

Solution A is by far the most explicit and safe. Solution B and C, without the addition of your own signal requires care and attention.

I wont say there are no use cases for muting `post_save` entirely. It should be an exception and an alert to maybe double check the need in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detail description and use cases.