# How can I disable a signal in a Django TestCase that uses fixtures?

Tags: django, unit-testing, signals

How can I disable a signal for all tests within a Django `TestCase` when I create data using `fixtures`?

The following approach adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38116770/1855919) does not work unfortunately. I suppose fixtures are applied before the `setUp` stage.

```
from django.db.models import signals
from django.test import TestCase


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ["some_data.json"]

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        signals.post_save.disconnect(sender=MyModel, dispatch_uid="some_signal_uid")

    def test_some_test(self):
        # do something


@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel,dispatch_uid="some_signal_uid")
def some_signal(sender, instance: MyModel, created: bool, **kwargs):
    # do something
```

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading) explain that the fixtures are loaded once for the class to speed up the tests. Try disconnecting in [`setUpClass`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/235b68135172c473e022045931719f047cf3dc4a/django/test/testcases.py#L1107) instead of `setUp`.

Comment: @Alasdair that worked indeed!