# post_save.disconnect does not work at all

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I'm trying to make Django not to send signal in one case. When adding a new instance of model `Delivery` (right after creating a `Job`) as an attribute of model `Job`, I don't want to send signal because the signal should alert admin that `Job` has been edited.

Unfortunately I can't make it work.

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=Job) # When Job is created or edited
def alert_admin(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        email.AdminNotifications.new_order(instance)
    else:
        email.AdminNotifications.edited_order(instance)

@receiver(post_save,sender=Job) # When job is created, I want to create a delivery object as an attribute of Job
def create_delivery(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        delivery,created_delivery = Delivery.objects.get_or_create(job=instance)
        instance.delivery = delivery
        delivery.save()
        post_save.disconnect(alert_admin)
        instance.save() # I DONT WANT TO SEND SIGNAL IN THIS CASE
        post_save.connect(alert_admin)
```

Where is the problem? I did this but I still recieve two alerts - `New Order` and `Edited Order`.

Comment: Does this solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487128/django-temporarily-disable-signals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are listening to the same signal twice.

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=Job) # When Job is created or edited
def alert_admin(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    ###

@receiver(post_save,sender=Job):
def create_delivery(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
   ###
```

You are assuing that `create_delivery` will be called first. But that does not seem to happen. `alert_admin` appears to be called first. So what ever signal disabling that you do in `create_delivery` just goes waste.

Django does not provide any guarantees or controls over the order in which signals are fired ([what's the order of post_save receiver in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990146/whats-the-order-of-post-save-receiver-in-django))

You can add a simple flag to your instance to tell the signal processor that this signal does not need further processing.

```
if hasattr(instance,'signal_processed'):
     return
else:
    # do whatever processing
    instance.signal_processed = True
```